# Swift Core Data Predicate IN Clause

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm attempting to use an IN clause with an NSPredicate. I'm getting the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa000000000000611'

Here's the code:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Employee> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Employee")

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
     NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "lastName", ascending: true)
]

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY id IN %@", argumentArray: recentEmployeeIds)

fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController.init(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                                           managedObjectContext: FLCoreDataController.shared.mainObjectContext,
                                                                           sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                                           cacheName: nil)
fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self

try? fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
```

Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Comment: Remove the `argumentArray:` label.  You're only passing one argument to your predicate (which is an array), not an array of arguments.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hmm do not know but as of swift 5.7 you can no longer remove the argumentArray. It expects an array of arguments even if the argument is already an array. So you should add argumentArray: [testArray]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't show how you are defining `recentEmployeeIds`, but assuming its something like

```
let recentEmployeeIds:[Int] = ...
```

then you need to init the `NSPredicate` correctly.  There is no label for `argumentArray`

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY id IN %@", recentEmployeeIds)
```

Comment: Removing the argument was the solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: Swift 5.9: I had to drop the ANY and the argument label (argumentArray:) to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the `argumentArray anymore (tested in swift 5.7)

```swift
Let duplicates = [“id”, “id2”]
let findDuplicates = <#NSManagedObject#>.fetchRequest()
findDuplicates.predicate = NSPredicate(format: <#key#> IN %@", argumentArray: [duplicates])
```

The difference is that you put the array in an array so it gets inserted as the first item. You only have one %@ so there should be in the array only 1 argument, but as you pass `duplicates which has 2 items there will be an error. Wrapping it in an array solves that.